# Azure search - Which is the best way to follow API or Portal when there is two data sources one sql on VM & other the blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have the following scenario and we need to implement Azure search. We have to finalize the method/work flow of the process.

We have two data sources one Sql on VM & other the Blob storage. We need to combine data from both the sources to be in a single index & then to be searched. Which is the best way to implement API or portal?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use two different indexes, there's no way to combine both using portal. So you need to write some code that will merge information from both sources and push them to your Azure Search index.

Here's a sample using CosmosDB and Blob Storage, all you need to do is use Sql rather than cosmos Db and proper model your index:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources